# What's the snackbar direction issue in wavesurfer player?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Our WordPress theme using wavesurfer library and we got in trouble when we try rtl mode in WordPress, because player shouldn't be rtl in **rtl mode**.

Notice inside the mediaplayer id in the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDDTW.png

I overwrote ltr direction on parent tag #mediaPlayer on style.css and use `bloginfo()` and fixed the positionings of tags and buttons but wavesurfer **snackbar** starts filling rtl instead.

Library address: https://wavesurfer-js.org
Our site in progress: http://radiobinaam.com

Play the music and see the snackbar that starts from right instead of the left because inherited rtl from body but two wave tags in the pic is from the library codes and I can't give them styles.

I want to fix the code that player runs like main library in rtl body.

Comment: So... contact wavesurfer? That's like, step 1. You have an issue with software X, contact the people who make X, because maybe you found a bug that they need to know about so they can fix it, and automatically help _everyone_ when they roll out an update that fixes the bug.

Comment: i should make sure that's it is not my bug and then send report in github

Comment: That should have been step 0, yes, but remember: you can file a bug report and then discover it was your own bug, and then you can say that it was a false alarm and close it. That's fine. But SO is not the best place to _start_, it's the place where you _end_ once you've run out of options and nothing you tried, nothing you did, nothing your file, nothing you searched, allowed you to figure out your problem. So start with createing an [mcve], properly run through that exercise, and then you'll know whether it's your bug, or wavesurfer.